# How to create a regression with results from an experiment repeated three times using all three outcomes for the Y value in lm/glm?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-testing

This dataset has the results of an experiment repeated three times. How do I fit a regression to a 3 column matrix Y for these three columns of data in R if these columns were named y1, y2, y3 in the dataframe I'm using? I'm struggling to understand how (or if) lm/glm can do this. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: FYI, `glm` cannot do multiple variables in the response.

Answer (score 1):

The method is to use `cbind` in conjunction with `lm` as follows:

```
# say your data is called `df`
multivariateModel = lm(cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ ., data = df)
```

Now to properly compute a MANOVA for the model taking into account the multivariate distributions of the response variables you need the `car` package:

```
car::Manova(multivariateModel)
```

This will compute the correct "Type II Sum of Squares"